# Learn R or stats first?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I will soon start working a lot with statistical hypothesis testing and I plan to use R.

my question, should I first focus on learning R or the stats?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Matter of opinion; here's mine: Best to learn R and statistics together. Some computational help will make learning statistics easier. You will not fully appreciate the value of R unless you have some statistical problems to solve with R. // Maybe three hours intro to R before you start statistics. (Learning how to find the mean of 10 numbers; how to make a histogram of 100, etc.) Lots of online 'help' using R for statistics, much of it actually helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do statistics without a computer. You cannot do statistical computing without understanding what you're doing, i.e. statistics.

Having this said, probably every statistics course curriculum includes some degree of software and, if covering more advanced material, elements of programming. To do statistics (aka data science) you need to know it. So you need to learn both.

*As a side-note, it doesn't have to be R. R is great for doing statistics, but for solving simple, day-to-day problems python is equally good, while much easier to learn.*

Comment: ... not to mention many other programs or languages that could be helpful.